# Non Equijoin query using Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

How to write a non equijoin query in Hibernate using Criteria?

I am having employees table and grade table. I want to fetch the employee deails and job grade for each employee based on the salary for that employee.

Below is the SQL :

```
select e.empName, e.salary. g.grade
from employees e, grade g
where e.salary between g.lowest_sal and g.highest_sal
```

What will be the equivalent Criteria query for this?

Please let me know about this.

Comment: no way with the criteria API, which only accepts one entity in the from clause. Use HQL.

Comment: Can you use HQL or must it be a criteria query?

Comment: Since I am using Criteria API for the DAO call in my entire application, hence won't want to put some HQL in it... :(